# Need to turn a number into a date on Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I think we need VBA to do this but:
I need everything in column A to become a date following the number of the sheet.

i have 12 sheets named jan - fev - mar - abr ..... - dez (names of the month in portuguese)
In sheet "jan" i need everything that is typed on column A to become a date of month 01, like :

I type 5 in a15, it becomes 05/01/2024 (day/month/year)
If i type 12 in a17 on sheet abr(april) it becomes 12/04/2024
but i can't figure out how!

I already tried using chat gpt vba but it doesnt work.

Comment: You can use a `Workbook_SheetChange` event triggered macro to do this.

Comment: I think it's the wrong approach to have a sheet for each month. What are you going to do if you need to make a report for the whole year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the following code into the `ThisWorkbook` code sheet:

***Note: Code edited to test that worksheet is a *Month* sheet.***

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rg As Range, rgInt As Range
    Dim months, monthNum As Long, lastDay As Long, yr As Long
    
'Change if your abbreviations are different
months = Array("jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez")

'check that worksheet is a month sheet
    On Error GoTo exitsub
        monthNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sh.Name, months, 0)
    ' On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set rgInt = Intersect(Target, Sh.Columns(1))
    If Not rgInt Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            yr = Year(Date)
            lastDay = Day(DateSerial(yr, monthNum + 1, 0))
            
'ensure day number is valid

            For Each rg In rgInt
                If rg.Value >= 1 And rg.Value <= lastDay Then
                    rg.Value = DateSerial(yr, monthNum, rg.Value)
                Else
                    rg.ClearContents
                End If
            Next rg
    End If
    
exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You made it look so easy. lol Thank you really much!!!

Comment: If you let me ask one more question: I have this formula on google sheets =query(hstack(B41:B70;D41:D70);"Select Col1,sum(Col2) Where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''")

i'd like to make it work on excel, but i can't :( 

here's the idea behind the formula
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1evuTnCh4Oq60totOtgtXzjJA41YsSDYQoSuMmTegIhU/edit?usp=sharing

I need to transfer it to excel

Comment: @RafaelGuimarães your comment does not seem to have anything to do with my response to the question you asked. If you have another question, ask another question. Please familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RafaelGuimarães Please note that I have edited the code to also test that the sheet is a proper "Month" sheet, else it will cause an error which will also disable `Application.EnableEvents`